# how to create multiple pdf's from rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex

I want to generate multiple pdfs by calling two different rmarkdown files from 3rd markdown to generate 2 pdf's of the first 2 markdown files

Comment: Can't you just call `rmarkdown::render(<file>)` for the "first two markdown files" within a code chunk in the "third markdown"?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you would want is have the 3rd markdown file be the "parent" and the other 2 pdfs will be "child" and you can have the option to have them not even render in the document. They all have to be in the same directory to render properly as is. Please provide a minimal code example to work with. Thank you.

````
```{r, child=c('pdf_one.Rmd', 'pdf_two.Rmd')}
```
````